# Update custom Wordpress field using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update a custom field in Wordpress using Ajax (e.g having a form text input replace the custom field text by the click of a button).
I’m using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and following the example I found here but this doesn't seem to work:
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/use-update_field-with-ajax/

What I have done is:

(1) Add html form to my single-(post-type).php

```
<form id="test-form" action="">
<input type="text" name="input-test" value="<?php the_field('field-name'); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

(2) update_field function in functions.php (this is an ACF function)

```
function test_function() {
    $input_test = $_POST['input-test'];
    if (!isset($input_test) || $input_test == "") { $input_test = "Fall Back"; }
    update_field('field-name', $input_test);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_test_function',  'test_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_function','test_function' );
```

(3) Enqueue Js script in functions.php

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'functionality', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functionality.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

    wp_localize_script('functionality', 'MyAjax',
    array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce('myajax-post-comment-nonce')
    )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

(3) Create Javascript file js/functionality.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var ajaxurl = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
  var form = "#test-form";
  jQuery(form).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl + "?action=test_function",
      type: 'post',
      data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("FAILURE");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Not sure what i'm missing because i'm very new with Ajax. I just get 'success' but the field doesn't get updated. I've also tried a variation shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0Jw226QKAM with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `success` callback to be like this and it will work:

```
...
success: function(data) {
   console.log("SUCCESS!");
  $('name="input-test"').val(data)
},
...
```

Comment: this does not solve my problem.. what i need from the ajax request is to call the test_function() in order to update_field(..), so not sure how setting the value if the input is gonna help with that. plus for some reason the 'data' that the success function returns is empty.

Comment: What is the web developer tool say in the network section? can you add `print_r($_POST)` inside you function and post its output here?